# Two absolute values within a third one in an inequality.

Tags: inequality

> $$\bigl||x+1|-|x-1|\bigr| < 1$$

So I'm aware that this becomes

$$-1 < |x+1|-|x-1| < 1$$

I do AND between them, but I'm not sure how to get the result for each of the two equations. Do I solve it again as a normal inequality?

Comment: A systematic approach for expressions with $|\cdot |$ is to investigate intervals where $\cdot$ are positive and negative and write a table for it.

Comment: That's such a long way that I didn't feel it would be the right solution to begin with..

Comment: Sketch the function $x \mapsto |x+1| - |x-1|$ and the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the analysis in three parts.

### Part 1: $x<-1$

Here we have $|x+1|=-x-1$ and $|x-1|=-x+1$, so the inequality becomes
$$
|(-x-1)-(-x+1)|<1
$$
that is, $|-2|<1$, which is false.

### Part 2: $-1\le x\le 1$

Here we have $|x+1|=x+1$ and $|x-1|=-x+1$, so the inequality becomes
$$
|(x+1)-(-x+1)|<1
$$
that is, $|2x|<1$, so $-1/2<x<1/2$.

### Part 3: $x>1$

Here we have $|x+1|=x+1$ and $|x-1|=x-1$, so the inequality becomes
$$
|(x+1)-(x-1)|<1
$$
that is, $|2|<1$, which is false.

## Alternative

Square: $|x+1|^2-2|x^2-1|+|x-1|^2<1$ becomes
$$
2x^2+1<2|x^2-1|
$$
Square again:
$$
4x^4+4x^2+1<4x^4-8x^2+4
$$
that is
$$
4x^2<1
$$
which is $-1/2<x<1/2$.

Comment: The alternative is exactly what I was looking for. you are da bomb!

Comment: @SvenBeckmann Remember to justify why you can square both times.

Comment: Nicely done. FWIW the number of cases can be reduced to just two by first noting that $f(x)=\big| |x+1| - |x-1| \big|$ is an even function.